# Separate path for Element API plugin

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Is it possible to have a dev version path for the Element API plugin so we can keep live and dev API separated?

Answer (score 2):

Craft config files usually allow to return environment-specific arrays. So you could just configure different endpoints like so:

```php
return [
    '*' => [],
    '.com' => [
        'endpoints' => [
            'api/example<ext:(.json)?>' => function() {
                // example API config for live environment
            },
        ],
    ],
    '.dev' => [
        'endpoints' => [
            'api/example<ext:(.json)?>' => function() {
                // example API config for dev environment
            },
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Doh so the answer is PHP constants:

```
define('CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH', '../../craftdev/config/');
```

useful to know.

Comment: That'll change the path for _all_ your config files (including `db.php`, `general.php` and Redactor configs), though.